# Vertically center text in HTML email

Tags: css, email, html-email

I'm trying to center vertically some text in a TD. I've tried `valign: middle` in line styled, `vertical-align: middle` in the style tags in the head.

I can't figure out why this won't work as it seems to be working on my desktop version. Below is the code w/some css and the HTML segment. This will be rendered in mobile so my focus is Android and iPhone.

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 481px){
  .hideOnDesktop{display: none !important;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .iosMiddle{vertical-align: middle;}

    .hideMobile{display: none !important;}
    .showMobile{display: block !important;}


<tr>
  <td>
    <table bgcolor="#ed1848" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="121">
      <tr>
        <td width="112" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="middle" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><img src="images/image.jpg"  width="112" height="121" alt="" style="display: block;width: 112px; height:auto;" border="0" ></td>
       <td class="hideMobile" width="247" height="121"  valign="middle" bgcolor="#ed1848" style="text-align: left; font-size: 30px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">Thanks for <br>your interest.</td>
<!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
       <td class="showMobile hideOnDesktop iosMiddle" width="247" height="121" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ed1848" style="display: none; text-align: left; font-size: 20px;  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap">Thanks for your interest.</td>
<!--<![endif]-->
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm seeing `vertical-align: center;` in your code on the final `<td>` tag, although `valign` is correct and should take over when the style fails.

Comment: Thanks @chriskirknielsen - that was left over from me shooting in the dark for a bit. I removed it as it does not work.

Comment: Could we got a bit of insight as to how your classes work? And your issue is on the `showMobile` cell, correct?

Comment: @chriskirknielsen - you got it! Let me know if there is anything additional you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I figured it out! You need to use the show/hide classes on the container and not on the TD itself in order to make the vertical center work.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <table class="hideMobile" bgcolor="#ed1848" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="121">
      <tr>
        <td width="112" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="middle" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><img src="image.jpg"  width="112" height="121" alt="" style="display: block;width: 112px; height:auto;" border="0" ></td>

        <td class="hideMobile" width="247" height="121"  valign="middle" bgcolor="#ed1848" style="text-align: left; font-size: 30px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">Thanks for <br>your interest.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

<!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
<table class="showMobile hideOnDesktop" bgcolor="#ed1848" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="121" style="display: none;">
  <tr>
    <td width="112" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="middle" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><img src="image.jpg"  width="112" height="121" alt="" style="display: block;width: 112px; height:auto;" border="0" ></td>


        <td border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#ed1848" align="center" valign="middle" style="color: #ffffff; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; white-space: nowrap;">Thanks for your interest.</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
    <!--<![endif]-->
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is because using `display: block;` on your `<td>` changes it from its normal behaviour, which is `display: table-cell;`. You should be able to revert to your original code taking that into account.

Comment: Thanks @chriskirknielsen - I'll give it a try. It would help to not be so repetitive in my code.